# Adobe Air TouchEvent fires on nested MovieClips

Tags: actionscript-3, ios7, air

I use the following code which works fine.

However, it also makes nested MCs within the "zoo" MC draggable (I have three MCs inside of the parent "zoo" MC)

What I need is to only have/make the parent MC (zoo) draggable - and not its nested children.

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

var fl_DragBounds:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);

zoo.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, zoo_TouchBeginHandler);
zoo.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, zoo_TouchEndHandler);

function zoo_TouchBeginHandler(event:TouchEvent):void
    {

        event.target.startTouchDrag(event.touchPointID, false, fl_DragBounds);
    }

    function zoo_TouchEndHandler(event:TouchEvent):void
    {
        event.target.stopTouchDrag(event.touchPointID);
    }
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was the "target" that was wrong! and therefore propagation could not be stopped :-(

I changed

```
event.target.startTouchDrag(event.touchPointID, false, fl_DragBounds);
```

to

```
event.currentTarget.startTouchDrag(event.touchPointID, false, fl_DragBounds);
```

and it worked out just fine.

Hope this may help someone with the same problem?